# Inserting TinyMCE into dynamic textareas

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I am using jQuery to dynamically append HTML onto an intial HTML block on button click. The appended HTML contains a textarea which I wish to reaplace with a TinyMCE editor. Wordpress ising TinyMCE editor v4.1.x

```
   <div id="initial">
   </div>

   <div class="append">
        <div class="input_field">
            <textarea
                id="field_id_1"
                class="text_input"
                name="text_input[]"
                value=""
            ></textarea>
       </div>
  </div>
```

I can append the HTML correctly and I can find the text-area via ID fine, but I cannot seem to work out how to replace it with MCE? (Currently I am just searching for a static ID (field_id_1) before I move onto replacing the dynamic text-areas).

```
var fieldID = jQuery(parent).find("textarea#field_id_1"); //found ok

 tinymce.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, fieldID);
```

I still seem to get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined
```

Is this the correct method of replacing a text area with TinyMCE? Do I need the jQuery TinyMCE plugin or can I use jQuery with the built in Wordpress TinyMCE stuff? I have [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094094/tinymce-setcontent-dynamically-jquery-added-textarea) a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150826/when-using-javascript-to-dynamically-and-a-textarea-how-can-i-render-it-as-a-ti) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774560/adding-tinymce-to-dynamically-added-textarea?rq=1) threads, but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you seen [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053353/tinymce-execcommand-return-undefined)?

Comment: Why `("textarea.field_id_1")`found ok ? and where is `testID` coming from ?

Comment: @l2aelba Typo, fixed. `textarea.field_id_1` is the textareas element ID

Comment: And still why `("textarea.field_id_1")` ? class="field_id_1" ?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/

Comment: Another typo, fixed.